# Какой тип выражения имеют операторы приведения типов?

Tags: c++

Что возвращает `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`?

`rvalue` или `lvalue` ?

Comment: Я думаю, что вряд ли найдется желающих переписывать сюда для вас стандарт C++.  Вопрос, в том виде, как он сформулирован, слишком большой и должен быть закрыт.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, мне кажется вопрос совершенно конкретный, более того мне он показался довольно любопытным. Единственное, что я не могу понять, что может делать выражение `xxx_cast<SomeType>(some_variable) = something`. Т.е., видимо r-value, но в справочнике Лишнера я этого не нашел.

Comment: @andy.37 Я уверен, что вопрос вам кажется конкретным, потому что вы никогда не видели соответствующих разделов стандарта, посвященных этим операторам. Чем меньше знаний по какому-либо языку, тем чаще общие вопросы кажутся конкретными.

Answer (score 4):

rvalue или lvalue нельзя вернуть — это *свойство* выражения, его неотъемлемая часть. Будет ли выражение типа `method_cast<to>(from)` считаться lvalue зависит исключительно от `to`.

В целом, можно считать следующим образом: если `to` имеет вид `T&`, то выражение считается lvalue, в противном случае это не-lvalue. Это не вся правда, безусловно, но случаем с rvalue-ссылкой на «функциональный тип» можно пренебречь, я считаю.

Answer (score 1):

Все же позволю себе ответить, при всем уважении к VladfromNoscow.
Из его последнего комментария очевидно, что простого однозначного ответа на поставленный вопрос не существует, и это действительно так. Все зависит от `new_type` в выражении `xxx_cast<new_type>(expression)`
Ссылка не на стандарт, но для меня источник авторитетный:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast